# Exlude .php from .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have the following in my .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This works great, but i would like to exclude all .php files and have them serve up non-SSL pages. Can someone give me some help on how to achieve this please?

Comment: .html pages should continue to use SSL.

Comment: So accessing a .php URL should redirect you to non-SSL?

Comment: They have some provided code from Intel and other places that break when using SSL. The client just wants to just ignore the .php pages for now as the companies are supposed to update the widgets in 6 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .*(?!\.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule \.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```